# Error importing DB in MySQL 8.0.15 from a File

Tags: mysql

I want to import some data in MySQL 8.0.15, but I got this error

```
Preparing...
Importing db_2019-05-25.sql...
Finished executing script
ERROR 1231 (42000) at line 3949: Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER'
Operation failed with exitcode 1
```

Comment: @stickybit, please convert to answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` was already deprecated in [5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_create_user), already was the default there and has been removed in [8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html).

Simply remove the setting of it from the script.